# Is it necessary to name NUnit test DLLs with ".Test" for use with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, nunit

In all the examples I've seen where people are using MSBuildCommunityTasks to run NUnit test runs every single example uses a naming convention like this for their test DLLs:
.Test.dll
instead of:
Test.dll

I'm old and started using DOS when you could not start a search string with an asterisk.  I know MSBuild uses wildcards to find the test libs (CP-M backward compatibility).  But, it seems that now in a CMD prompt, I can search for *fred.dll and it will return only files that end in fred.dll no matter what's before fred.

My team leads are making a big stink about using the period "." in the file name so I thought it was worth asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a must to use period ".". The only reason your leads may be insisting for the use of that may be for some standards they follow all over the projects or something like that.

Other than that there is no such rules for NUnit to work or so on Test dlls.